# action after render a view (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would want to know if it is possible make different actions after render a view with codeigniter, something like:

```
public function my_function()
{
    $data['var1'] = $this->make_one_action();
    $data['var2'] = $this->make_other_action();
    $this->load->view('a_view', $data);
    //and now... more actions??
    $this->make_dataBase_action();
}
```

what I want to do is process some data of the data base, but don´t make to wait the user to this processing (when the new view will not show this actions on the data base to user).

And a little more... (a different question, but related), could I do something like this:

```
public function my_function()
{
    $data['var1'] = $this->make_one_action();
    $data['var2'] = $this->make_other_action();
    redirect(base_url()); //here is the difference
    //and now... more actions??
    $this->make_dataBase_action();
}
```

In this case I would want to redirect the user to a new page and after make the processing on the data base.

Thank you.

Comment: So, you want to deliver the page to the user and *then* run some database queries?

Comment: Hello @RocketHazmat Yes, it is what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting will stop the PHP script from executing, if you want you can load the page and send ajax request to trigger queries

Assuming you are using jQuery: on your Controller add the method 
`function executeDbOnpageLoad(){$this->make_dataBase_action();} //add _get to the method name if CI Version 2`

and add this line to your "a_view.php"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax("index.php?/ControllerName/executeDbOnpageLoad()")
})
```

(You'll need to make it a bit more secured and make sure user won't trigger this function many times as he want)

Comment: Hi @DanielKrom.. but... in this case the user will need to wait until the queries of the database finish, no??

Comment: yes, better solution is to load the page and to send ajax request to trigger queries

Comment: but, in some of my cases, the view I am thinking to show is render from two or three different places (different functions, different controllers...), and the queries on the database would not be triggered in all cases, also, in other cases, the queries are for audit, and I don´t want to expose a uri where modify this audit (because I imaging that you are talking about make ajax request on the document ready...)